# javac not working on Win 8.1

Tags: java, windows

I installed jdk 8_u25 on my Windows 8.1 ,but commands javac and javap aren't working. I went to environment variables and changed the value of Path to

C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin​

and still isn't working. My program files in on C: itself. Kindly help. Thank You.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Which error do you get?

Comment: I don't see any JDK in your path variable, only JRE

Comment: I had followed a method suggested by another stack overflow  post so that's where the jre came from. Anyways got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install a JDK on Windows, as well as installing the JDK it also installs a separate "public" copy of the JRE for use by tools like web browser Applets and Java Web Start.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin​

looks like the bin directory of this public JRE installation rather than the JDK itself, and the public JRE does not include `javac`.

You need to add the JDK bin directory to your path instead of the public JRE one.